# How to add a Postgres unique constraint that applies to multiple columns, checking that columns are unique with each other?

Tags: postgresql

I am creating an application that uses a postgres db backend. A user can log in to the application using either their username or email, so I'd like to add a constraint to the user table to ensure that all usernames and emails are mutually unique. In other words, no user can have a username that is the same as any other user's username or email address, nor can they have an email address that is the same as any other user's username or email address, but a user can have an email address that is the same as their username.

Is there a way I can do this using constraints, or would I need to use some sort of trigger?

Here's the table, with irrelevant columns removed:

```
CREATE TABLE user_info
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  email character varying(64) NOT NULL,
  username character varying(64) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT user_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've hashed through 2 or 3 ways to handle this, and I am falling back to suggest either do the trigger before insert (and throw error) or simply handle it in the application logic before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use a constraint trigger to reject invalid rows, e.g.:

```
create function reject_user_info_dups() returns trigger as $$
begin
  if exists (select 1
               from user_info
              where (email = new.email
                 or email = new.username
                 or username = new.email
                 or username = new.username)
                and id <> new.id)
  then
    raise exception 'dup row found for (%,%)', new.email, new.username;
  end if;
  return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create constraint trigger reject_user_info_dups
after insert or update on user_info
for each row execute procedure reject_user_info_dups();
```

For the above to perform properly, you'll want (unique) indexes on email and username.

A slight variation of the above would be this one:

```
  if exists (select 1
               from user_info
              where array[email, username] && array[new.email, new.username]
                and id <> new.id)
    ...
```

If you go that route, add a gin index on array[email, username] instead:

```
create index on user_info using gin ((array[email, username]));
```

You can then use that same index to fetch user data during login attempts:

```
select * from user_info where ? <@ array[email, username];
```

Another way is to create a convoluted set unique indexes:

```
create unique index on user_info (email);
create unique index on user_info (username);
create unique index on user_info ((least(email, username)));
create unique index on user_info ((greatest(email, username)));
```

(I imagine there's also a way to do this with some kind of exclude constraint on `array[email, username] with &&`, but gin doesn't support exclude constraints, and gist coughs varchar[] has no default operator class for access method errors.)